# What does mean when create channel like "reloadCh chan chan error"

Tags: go, channel, prometheus

I am new to golang, begin to write some monitor exporters based on prometheus client-go, found the source code of promethues have such code of definition of channel var

```
reloadCh     chan chan error
```

and instantiate it using

```
reloadCh:    make(chan chan error)
```

as usual, one channel can be define with

```
reloadCh     chan error
```

why extra `chan` is here ?

Comment: `chan error` is a channel of errors. `chan chan error` is a channel of channels.

Comment: got it, thanks. this is really confusing me.

Answer (score 4):

`chan chan error` is a channel of channels of errors. One of usual applications of using channels of channels is getting a response or error to a request (this is in fact the case in prometheus exporters you were looking at). The reason for using channel of channels is that it allows you to choose where you want to have your answer communicated to (in contrary to using the same channel for sending request and receiving response).

**An example:**

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    requestChan := make(chan chan error)

    // Starting the service goroutine
    go goroutine(requestChan)

    // Send 5 requests and collect errors
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Request %v\n", i+1)

        // Make channel that will be used to communicate error back to main
        errorChan := make(chan error)

        requestChan <- errorChan

        err := <-errorChan
        fmt.Printf("Erro received: %v\n\n", err)

        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    }
}

func goroutine(requestChan <-chan chan error) {

    for {
        select {
        case errChan := <-requestChan:
            fmt.Println("Got request from requestChan")
            errChan <- someOperation()
        }
    }
}

// someOperation that will sometimes return nil error and sometimes it will return error
func someOperation() error {

    if rand.Intn(10) > 5 {
        return nil
    }

    return errors.New("error for someOperation")
}
```

Run it on [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4l57Hqw9CLJ).

A great explanation of this concept is given in [Advanced Go Concurrency Patterns](https://youtu.be/QDDwwePbDtw?t=997) talk by Sameer Ajmani.